# Editing GridView For dynamically generated Field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

My GridView is as follows

It has EmptyDatatemplate  and Command Field

```
   <asp:GridView ID="AGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="2000px"   RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
           &nbsp;
       </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="80px" EditText="Edit">
         <ItemStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" />
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="AAddOn" />
         </asp:CommandField>
  </asp:GridView>
```

GridView Looks like

```
Name   Age  Country
A      10    NNN       Edit  
B      23    NNN       Edit
```

Now if i click on edit i need only Age Column to be edited

If i give  AGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex entire row is edited

In codebehind

```
   Private Sub AGridView_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles AGridView.RowEditing
            Try
                AGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex

                AGridView.DataSource = SessionItems.ADataset.Tables("AHello")
                AGridView.DataBind()

            Catch ex As Exception
                SetErrorMsg(ex.Message.ToString, "Error")
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple. Whatever the columns you don't want editable, just add those in **DataKeyNames** property of grid. Try this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="AGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="2000px"   RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataKeyNames = "Name,Country" >
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
           &nbsp;
       </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="80px" EditText="Edit">
         <ItemStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" />
          <HeaderStyle CssClass="AAddOn" />
         </asp:CommandField>
  </asp:GridView>


    Private Sub AGridView_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles AGridView.RowEditing
                Try

                  Dim colsToNotEdit As List<string>

//C# code 

        for (int i = 0; i < AGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if(AGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text !="age")
          colsToNotEdit.Add(grdToDisplay.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
    }
            AGridView.DataKeyNames = colsToNotEdit.ToArray()
     AGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex

                    AGridView.DataSource = SessionItems.ADataset.Tables("AHello")
                    AGridView.DataBind()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    SetErrorMsg(ex.Message.ToString, "Error")
                End Try
            End Sub
```

Comment: I have Little problem here..My columns are dynamically generated.Iam Binding my gridview with datatable which generates columns dynamically.                  Is it possible in gridview Whatever the columns need to be editable can be added like you have mentioned in datakeynames instead of column not needed to be edited..

Comment: I got your problem. The possible solution I can see, in RowEditing event loop for gridview columns to create a string array with non editable fields. Then assign DataKeyNames to the array.

Comment: Can you help me with code..How to bind Datakeyname with gridview rowediting  generated values as you mentioned with above scenerio

Comment: edited the answer. The answer have loop in C#, change it to VB.NET. The code may have few syntax error. Need to leave.

Comment: Hi what is grdToDisplay,colsToNotEdit means in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to not use the AutoGenerateColumns functionality and specify your column templates.

This way you can specify the ItemTemplate, EditTemplate or FooterTemplate for each column.

So for a column that you dont want to edit, ie. Name use `<asp:BoundField>` and for age use:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label>Bind Me</asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox>Bind Me</asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Edit: When using Dynamic Column Names

If you have a datatable that contains your data, lets say `dtRowData`.

You should have a piece of code where you assign the datatable to the grid:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dtRowData;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can add a loop in before the databind call as follows:

```
string DataKeyNames = "";
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtRowData.Columns)
{
    if(dc.Name != "Age")
       DataKeyNames += dc.Name + ",";
}
```

And then before Binding Set `GridView1.DataKeyNames = DataKeyNames`

You will probably need to do a substring on DataKeyNames to remove the trailing ,

Comment: My column is Dynamically generated..Iam binding my gridview with datatable which generates column dynamically hence i cannot use item template..

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the columns in code? If not you can still specify the columns just use the datafield property to specify the database column this must link to.

Comment: Yes my datatable is retrieving columns dynamically..For example  Columns may be A,B,C   and next time it varies  so it can be A,B,C,D,E..So i cannot use template field as you mentioned or use datakeyname as Vicky Mentioned in below post..Is there any alternative

Comment: You could still use datanames as mentioned above, you would just have to build the string dynamically after you have retrieved your datatable based on its column names and then set the datakeynames value before you databind

Comment: Edited my answer to give you an idea